Intellij disable fix with AI intention
Since an update Intellij shows the fix with AI button shown in the image at the top of my intentions. This is irritating, especially because I do not have access to the JetBrains AI Pro feature. How can I remove this intention from this menu? I am using intellij idea ultimate 2024.3 on macros.

I tried:

disabling AI assistant for my project
disabeling AI Assistant in the editor/intentions menu


This is really obnoxious.

Try "Shift+Shift" and then type "Registry" to open the Registry. Find "llm.fix.with.ai.enabled" and disable it.
